# How to run a loop equal to the size and value of an array.

Tags: arrays, ruby

The Input of the @behaviour will be a something like LMLMLM which will be stored in an Array ["L", "M", "L", "M", "L", "M"]. 
I want to run the if statements in the rover_behaviour to all of the characters in the array. So if it is LMLMLM - it will run the if statement 6 times to each of the characters. I just have no idea how to run that loop?

```
def rover_behaviour
 puts " \n Please input the behaviour of the rover(L,R & M):    "
 input = gets.chomp.upcase
 @behaviour = input.scan /\w/

  if @behaviour[0] == "L" 
    move_left

  else if
  @behaviour[0] == "R" 
  move_right

  else if
  @behaviour[0] == "M"
    move_forward

  end
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `each`.

Comment: You're *still* using `else if` instead of `elsif` which is a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to handle each character in a multi-character input? `each` is the key word:

```
@behaviors = input.scan /\w/
@behaviors.each do |behavior|
  case behavior
  when "L"
    move_left
  when "R"
    move_right
  when "M"
    move_forward
  end
end
```

Also I switched to a `case` statement which can tidy up `if` statements, especially if they get more complex.

Comment: It looks like the instance variable is actually extraneous and can be removed by inlining `input.scan` into the `each` directly.

Comment: @tadman It certainly can. I only included that line because I was going to make a style point about using plurals for arrays, but then promptly forgot :) (at least it allowed me to spell "behavior" correctly :) )